# Why doesn't this simple Rails migration update my database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I've got a very simple migration that adds a single boolean column:

```
class AddMuteToPreferences < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :preferences, :mute_audio, :boolean, :default => false
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :preferences, :mute_audio
  end
end
```

I run the migration:

```
== 81 AddMuteToPreferences: migrating =========================================
-- add_column(:preferences, :mute_audio, :boolean, {:default=>false})
   -> 1.9043s
== 81 AddMuteToPreferences: migrated (1.9047s) ================================
```

Looks peachy, right?  But, for some reason, there's still no mute_audio column in my preferences table.

I can't figure it out.  I've executed add_column before with no problems.

Has anyone ever seen this behavior before?

Comment: Are you viewing database of the same environment you executed migration in?

Comment: Well, I'm just doing rake db:migrate (no env specified).

And I'm doing ruby script/console to examine the model after the migration.  

In both cases it should default to development, right?

Comment: Indeed, but double checking doesn't hurt. Also you may want to try migration down. If it passes - the column was added indeed. Tailing log/development.log should help too!

Comment: Whoa, you're right... it executed on my production db!  I think my sysadmin changed some config file.  I'm trying to figure out exactly what.  Thanks for your help, Eimantas!

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason for rails to fail the add of the column. You are probably looking in the wrong database.

The best way to debug this is to enter rails console mode:

```
script/console development
```

And create a new preference object and give mute_audio a value:

```
>> p = Preference.new
(...)
>> p.mute_audio = true
```

After the first command, you should see some output containing info about the newly created object. You should see that it has `mute_autio: false`. If setting the attribute mute_audio does not output an error, there's no problem and the new added column is there.